# Refreshing data source autocomplete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to refresh my autocomplete source after a keyup event on my input field.

My code is the following :

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="myInput" type="text">
</div>
```

```js
var nb = data.length;
var myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
  myArray.push({
    value: data[i],
    label: data[i],
  });
}

$("#myInput").autocomplete({
  source: myArray,
  minLength: 1,
  select : function(event, ui) {
    // someCode;
  }
}).on("focus", function() {
  $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

On initialization, my autocomplete source is an empty array. The array is updated every time after the user presses a key. The problem is that when I populate `myArray`, the list doesn't show. I have to press arrow keys (up or down) to open the list.

Moreover, when making a new search (another keyup) with the list opened, it stays the same and I don't have my list updated.

So I have 2 questions :

1. How do I let the list opened when user have the focus on the input field?
2. How to refresh my source when making a new search?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it myself, I know it's not the cleanest wat to do it, but here's my solution :

Destroy the autocomplete before recreating it :

```
$("#myInput").autocomplete("destroy");
```

Force it to lose focus, and then force focus on the input :

```
$("#myInput").blur();
$("#myInput").focus();
```

As I said, far from the cleanest, but transparent to the user...